# Kdb+/q: Looping over initialised list

Tags: kdb

Let's say I create an empty table:

```
test:([] name:`symbol$(); balance:`int$());
```

Now let's populate this list with one row:

```
insert[`test;(`John;1001)];
```

Now if I want to loop over this table as follows:

```
n:0;
k:0;
f:{x%100}
do[count test; k+:f[test.balance[n]]; n+:1]
```

Then it gave me an error because it tried to use (evaluate) the empty initialisation value with the function `f`.

Is there any particular reason why this doesn't work?

And how can I make sure it *does* work?

Comment: you function `f` looks weird to me. Are you trying to do a division?

Comment: @WooiKentLee Yes I am. Little typo there :P

Comment: @WooiKentLee And this example is just for illustrative purposes. Actual code looks different but does the same thing (more or less).

Comment: I can only deduce that `test.balance[n]` is not returning a proper value for `f` to work. More insight to `test.balance` will be helpful.

Comment: @WooiKentLee `test.balance` is the column of the `test` table. That syntax is allowed too right?

Comment: As I can see, `test` table has a symbol column `name`. It is not possible to divide the table by numbers that way when not all the columns are numerical type, it will result in `'type` error. You might need to rethink what output should `test.balance` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing may work but it's far from best practice. Loops and indices are not the way to go.

What you're looking for is essentially

```
test:([] name:`symbol$(); balance:`int$());
insert[`test;(`John;1001)];
insert[`test;(`Jane;2002)];

q)select sum f[balance] from test
balance
-------
30.03
```

Comment: So queries is the way to go. I see. I'm using the results in sequential functions, so I still have to get used to assigning query output to variables (Coming from OOP).

Comment: Yeah, bit of an adjustment! If you wanted to extract only the value (30.03 in my example above) and assign it to a variable you use "exec". For example:

myvar:exec sum f[balance] from test

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out for my actual code. I suspect this is also better performance wise?

Comment: Yes, much better performance-wise. Kdb performs at its best when operating on vectors/lists (which is exactly what the balance column is), rather than on single items

Comment: I have another very short question (which should be a no-brainer for you): what's the best way to subtract a column of a table to a list? (Let's say column `balance` from the example).

Comment: You mean how to *extract* a column as a list? That's exec again. 

mylist:exec balance from test;

If you asking how to subtract from the balance you do something like:

exec balance-myOtherList from test

Comment: `exec` is more powerful than I thought. It was the first thing indeed. Thanks again.